# NTFS on Linux for backing up Windows systems

Tags: linux, windows, backup, ntfs

Currently I have a Windows based backup "server" which has access to some shares on other windows systems, and uses `robocopy` to pull all the new/mofified files from those systems, without modifying any NTFS attributes like creation, modification or permissions, every couple of hours.

It works good.

I want to replace it with a Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) backup server, but my impression is that I will then lose all the NTFS attributes. Specially the creation and modification times are very important to me, they should never ever get modified/deleted.

Is there a way to create a copy onto a NTFS formatted HDD, so that the files are backed up 1:1? So that if I take that drive and plug it into one of the backed up machines, the backed up folders are identical to those which they do back up?